# JShell <Shift+tab i> is not working properly in jdk 9

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

While trying JShell in Fedora I tried to used snippet transformation shortcut  as specified  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/snippets.htm#JSHEL-GUID-63DBC3E7-6EF2-498D-8638-94867ED10F76) , but I think It is not working
It is showing

> Unexpected character after Shift-Tab.  Use "i" for auto-import or "v" for variable creation.  For more information see:
>
> /help shortcuts

I tried the ways that specified in those messages but still same result

any Ideas or I am doing something wrong?

> $javac -version

javac 9

> java -version

openjdk version "9"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9+181)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

*Here is what I am trying to do :*

> jshell$ new JFrame

I typed `new JFrame` and then pressed ***shift+tab i***(holding shift pressed and releasing tab and then pressing i).
as per the docs it should show me something like:

```
0: Do nothing
1: import: javax.swing.JFrame
Choice:
```

but it is showing

> Unexpected character after Shift-Tab. Use "i" for auto-import or "v" for variable creation. For more information see:

instead

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? could you share a sample of what is expected and what is it that you end up with?

Comment: @nullpointer:I updated my question

Comment: You wrote : 'holding shift pressed and releasing tab and then pressing i'. That gives **shift+tab I** with an uppercase `i`. Try **shift+tab i** with an lowercase `i`.

Comment: @blafasel:Yes ,thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way the shortcuts work is as follows :

*Press Shift+Tab..Release both..Press 'i' or 'v'*

***--- Use Cases ---***

1. Type a constant for e.g.

   ```
   Enter '1' 
   Press Shift+Tab then Press 'v'
   Provide a variable name
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   Provide a variable name and you are done with.
   ```

   [image]
2. Use a java internal class e.g. `JFrame`

   ```
   Enter 'new JFrame'
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   Provide your choice
   ```

Comment: thanks .It is both shift+tab that we need to release not shift Tab key individual

Comment: Still not working properly:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8177650

My experience is that it works for classes from the JDK.
For jars added on classpath it works sometimes.
For added modules it does not work though the packages can be imported using the import keyword.